# Lightroom does'n switch to GeForce

Tags: nvidia-geforce, adobe-lightroom

I have a LR 4/5, but not of them switch to GeForce GT630M on my laptop, photoshop, cinema 4d, illustrator and other graphic soft work normally through the GeForce, but not the LR. anybody know the reasen? pls, help

**EDIT:**
Acer V3-571G Intec Core i5-3210M 2.5GHz (Turbo boost up to 3.1GHz), 8Gb Ram
Windows 7 x64 Ultimate, GeForce GT 630M 2Gb (drivers ver. 327.23), Lightroom 4.*/5.*

Comment: Please provide details of your laptop. The more detail you provide the better the chance that we can help you.

Comment: @Tog, i edited my post, check it, pls

Comment: The reason why I asked was because there may be a laptop OEM  (ACER) utility that can  modify  which applications require 3-D acceleration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lightroom does not utilize the GPU for performance improvements and this is clearly stated in the [Lightroom help](http://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/kb/optimize-performance-lightroom.html#main_Optimize_your_hardware_and_OS).

> Video cards
>
> Lightroom requires a video card that can run the monitor at its native resolution. Built-in, default cards that ship with most desktop or laptop systems typically suffice for Lightroom

Adobe Lightroom will not benefit from dedicated GPU or 3D as Lightroom doesn't use it. You are running 64-bit (I suppose) on an x64 OS with 8GB RAM, so you don't have to worry about VGA. Lightroom benefits the most from CPU and RAM.